# Android SDK location vs Build Server, how to set it?

Tags: android, build, sdk, gradle, environment-variables

I want to create a build server for my Android Application. I am working with TeamCity. My problem is:

1. Build server which is a PC (Windows) doesn't see Android SDK location.
2. PC on which server runs has ANDROID_HOME set in right way.
3. My application uses Gradle build system.

What I need to do is to make my build server use environment location (ANDROID_HOME) during build of my app. What have I already tried?

- I used local.properties in my Android Project. I tried to set ANDROID_HOME parameter to sdk.dir in various ways for example.

> sdk.dir = ANDROID_HOME

result - error:

> The SDK directory 'E:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\a6d423a9d6e29c40\ANDROID_HOME' does not exist.

So as you can see, server adds some strange directory before. Same goes for: $ANDROID_HOME or %ANDROID_HOME%.

- When I set path manually and point to SDK direction on server so:

> sdk.dir = /Program Files (x86)/android-studio/sdk

Then server builds the project and everything is right. ANDROID_HOME environment variable is set to same location as this.

- I deleted local.properties and I get this:

> SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.

So how I understand this is: if I won't have local.properties in my project it will look for SDK path in ANDROID_HOME environment variable. Like I said, on my server environment variable is set and I've checked it many times. It doesn't work. (I tried it also on MAC X OS, terminal displays ANDROID_HOME as /Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk but for example Android Studio is able to build project only if I hardcode path in local.properties. It doesn't want to accept ANDROID_HOME variable in any way.)

---

How can I set environment variable in local.properties so I don't have to hardcode it to make it work?

Comment: `ANDROID_HOME` should not the value of the `sdk.dir` property. It's the name of the environment variable that you need to create with the value of the path to your SDK. For `sdk.dir` you should be able to use  `sdk.dir=c:\Program Files (x86)\android-studio\sdk`

Comment: I know that will work, but it won't work on others PC. I mean when I work on my MAC and my SDK dir is /Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk and I push it to GIT repo, then other person that would like to pull it will pull also my local.properties that won't compile. Furthermore if I push my src.dir from MAC when build server  will give error on run, because it won't find SDK on PC/Windows (because SDK dir on PC is /Program Files (x86)/android-studio/sdk and I pushed my local.properties with /Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk). That's why usage of ANDROID_HOME for each PC would be optimal

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for interesting link. It is a great project but in my situation it doesn't give me what I really need. I managed to configure my TaxiCity project by doing:

1. Every worker has it's own local.properties on PC that are not pushed to repo with commits.
2. TeamCity builds project from repo but there is no local.properties - because of that he will look for ANDROID_HOME or give error if won't find it.
3. Because setting ANDROID_HOME environment variable on PC which is a server doesn't work, I found a workaround which is: setting ANDROID_HOME variable inside TeamCity server file - buildAgent.properties
4. TeamCity can't find local.properties (because it's not on repo), gets SDK location installed on server from ANDROID_HOME variable located in buildAgent.properties file

Comment: Setting ANDROID_HOME worked for me - I had to install Android Studio first and download the android SDK on the build server.

Answer (score 4):

I hope that this will help solve the problem:
https://github.com/JakeWharton/sdk-manager-plugin

Comment: Interesting, I'm testing it now.

Comment: This works almost perfectly. But is dedicated for Linux/MAC. Build server on build task creates local.properties with right path to sdk.dir but the slashes are in wrong direction. ("\" instead of "/") I have to change it manually and then it works from now on.