# Set Android_HOME for TeamCity build server

Tags: android, gradle, teamcity

I have tried to execute a Gradle task in TeamCity for an Android project, but it fails with following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
```

I search about that and found following suggestion:
[Android SDK location vs Build Server, how to set it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22765997/android-sdk-location-vs-build-server-how-to-set-it)

```
setting ANDROID_HOME variable inside TeamCity server file - buildAgent.properties
```

I opened buildAgent.properties under TeamCity/BuidAgent/conf, and add following:

```
sdk.dir=/Users/ali/Library/Android/sdk
```

but it still fails with the same error message. Do you know what am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Documentation can be found : https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Project+and+Agent+Level+Build+Parameters

This is what I needed to set:

```
env.ANDROID_HOME=/Users/ali/Library/Android/sdk
```